# How to fix 'cannot add foreign key constraint' error using uuid instead of incrementing primary key

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**EDIT**: Solved, I forgot parentheses on `->primary()` on the uuid field.

I'm trying to switch my app from incrementing id's to uuid. For now I've only switched to uuid on my `create_users_table`. The first table that has a foreign key pointing to my users table is `create_groups_table` When I try to run the migration my foreign key constraint fails.

I've tried different values for the foreign key, but to no avail.

Here is the relevant code.

create_users_table:

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary;
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

create_groups_table:

```
    Schema::create('groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->uuid('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I expect the migration to run, but I get:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `groups` add constraint `groups_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: comment on your question and mark your answer as answered :D

Answer (score 0):

I forgot parentheses on `->primary()` on the uuid field:

```
   Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```